# c# System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl method have a bug?

Tags: routes, html.actionlink

My English not wel, please bear with me a lot.
routes in Global.asax file:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default","{controller}/{action}/{Page}/{id}",new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Page = 0, id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I used @Html.Action write

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText","About",null,new{id="_ID"})
```

in View page.
When opening url with

```
http://localhost/Home/About
```

in the broswer,The url result In the View page is:

```
http://localhost/Home/About
```

It's right! 
But When opening url with

```
http://localhost/Home/About/8
```

The url result In the View page is

```
http://localhost/Home/About/8
```

too. Why?
This is a bug?

I want url is http://localhost/Home/About, 
Because the value of parameter named routeValues is null.

Comment: Why are you opening 'http://localhost/Home/About/8' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use null as your RouteValue then it will use the current RouteValues.

Rather use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText","About",new{page=0, id=""},new{id="_ID"})
```